# Play framework sub-projects - write to console from all sub-projects?

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, subproject

I am developing a web application using Play! Framework 2.2.1 and Java 8.
Recently i divided my project to multiple sub-projects , and now it is seems to be that only one sub-project can write to the console (System.out).

For example , when i have Global objects in 2 sub-projects (Already handled how to do this ) and i override onRouteRequest at both of them , only one of them (Apparently the first one to run) could write to the console.

How can i fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Even if you have multiple sub-projects you have essentially 1 play-application. I guess your `Global` objects are extending `ApplicationSettings` but these are applied to the same application. Hence, if you override things in both... only the latest override will work.

Comment: May be if you really really need this... you can start multiple play applications ( I am not really sure... if that will be simple or even possible ).

Comment: Well actually I know that there is only one global object so I did a reflection from the root project to the sub project's global object. Still, only one of my sub projects can write to console...